# Why does BitmapFactory.decodeResource with inPreferredConfig=RGB565 scale up my pictures x2?

Tags: java, android

I have a resource image. If I read its dimensions without actually decoding, all is fine (even if asking for RGB565). If I decode into RGB565 color format the Android API provides me with dimensions double too wide and too high.

Is this a bug in Android?

```
private static Bitmap decodeBitmapAsRGB565( Resources res, int resId ) {
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    int origW, origH;

    opt.inJustDecodeBounds= true;       // don't decode contents, just get the dimensions
    {
        // Get original picture's dimensions
        //
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource( res, resId, opt );
        Log.v("", String.format("*** Original: %d x %d", opt.outWidth, opt.outHeight));     // 1532x2048

        origW= opt.outWidth;
        origH= opt.outHeight;

        opt.inPreferredConfig= Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

        BitmapFactory.decodeResource( res, resId, opt );
        Log.v("", String.format("*** RGB565: %d x %d", opt.outWidth, opt.outHeight));       // 1532x2048
    }
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds= false;

    opt.inPreferredConfig= Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;       // needed for 'EFFECT_REDEYES'

    final Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource( res, resId, opt );

    // Check that we got the size of the original
    //
    int w= bmp.getWidth();
    int h= bmp.getHeight();

    if ((w!=origW) || (h!=origH)) {
        String s; Log.wtf("", s= String.format("Bitmap dimensions screwed: (%d,%d) vs. (%d,%d)", w,h, origW,origH));
        throw new RuntimeException(s);
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: `RGB_565` has nothing to do with the width and height of your resource. What could cause this behaviour is the screen density

Comment: Sounds fair. So how would I take counter measures if I don't want the scaling to happen. By the way, if I don't request RGB_565 I get the resource's original dimensions (no scaling).

Comment: put it inside `drawable-nodpi`

Comment: more than likely, it's the density of the device you're running on.  Whenever you decode resources, Android takes into account the resolution of the asset but also the density of the device. If there isn't a corresponding asset in your res/drawable_xdpi or ...mdpi or .. ...hdpi, then Android will scale the drawable accordingly

Comment: Thanks, it's all clear now. I was indeed misusing the resource things for something they are not. If @blackbelt wants to write the 4 words as an answer, I'll be glad to accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Resources` are scaled accordingly to the device's screen density. If you want to avoid the scaling you can put the resources inside the  `drawable-nodpi` directory.